# "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" on Access query from PHP

Tags: php, sql, ms-access-2010

I'm writing a SQL query in PHP against an Access database and I'm getting this error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: -3100 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(FROM [Tbl_Invoice_Details], INNER JOIN [Tbl_Product_Table] ON [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Product_ID] = [Tbl_Product_Table.Product_ID]) WHERE Invoice_ID = Pa_RaM000'."

Here is my query:

```
SELECT [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Product_ID], 
            [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Seed Size], [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Ref2], [Tbl_Invoice_Details.RefNo], [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Quantity Ordered],
            [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Quantity Delivered], [Tbl_Invoice_Details.PricePerUnit], [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Extended],
            [Tbl_Product_Table.Product_ID], [Tbl_Product_Table.Hybrid Brand], (FROM [Tbl_Invoice_Details] INNER JOIN [Tbl_Product_Table]
            ON [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Product_ID] = [Tbl_Product_Table.Product_ID]) WHERE Invoice_ID = ?
```

Why is it failing?

Comment: Why do you have a comma after `[Tbl_Product_Table.Hybrid Brand]`?

Comment: If you don't have any experience writing SQL queries by hand, consider creating them in Access's visual editor, assuming you're familiar with that, then copying the SQL that's generated.

Comment: Please use alias so that `Tbl_Invoice_Details` wouldn't be repeated.. :)

Comment: why you use ". " between sql

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan That's the string concatenation operator in PHP. (Though personally I'd probably have used heredoc syntax for something this long...)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is failing because everything enclosed in square brackets is interpreted as a single name, so

```sql
SELECT [Tbl_Invoice_Details.Product_ID] ... FROM [Tbl_Invoice_Details]
```

is the same as

```sql
SELECT [Tbl_Invoice_Details].[Tbl_Invoice_Details.Product_ID] ... FROM [Tbl_Invoice_Details]
```

Access does not allow us to define field names that contain periods, so that will never work.

What you meant was

```sql
SELECT [Tbl_Invoice_Details].[Product_ID] ... FROM [Tbl_Invoice_Details]
```

which is (one of) the correct way(s) to express

```sql
SELECT [TableName].[FieldName] ... FROM [TableName]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following query:

```
SELECT i.Product_ID, i.[Seed Size], i.Ref2, i.RefNo, i.[Quantity Ordered], 
       i.[Quantity Delivered], i.PricePerUnit, i.Extended, p.[Hybrid Brand]
FROM Tbl_Invoice_Details i
INNER JOIN Tbl_Product_Table p ON i.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
WHERE i.Invoice_ID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the comma after [Tbl_Product_Table.Hybrid_Brand] isn't needed..
And maybe your invoice id between anchors?
So
`WHERE Invoice_ID = Pa_RaM000`
turns into
`WHERE Invoice_ID = "Pa_RaM000"`